# Was Leonardo da Vinci an atheist?

Tags: individuals

I read in a William Smith Quora answer that this question "is easily answered" because Vasari wrote that Leonardo, on his deathbed, asked for the sacraments. I don't say this is false, but it looks a bit hasty conclusions. How reliable is Vasari's anecdote? In my experience, today religious are usually very nice persons, and surely they would find a cruelty impose sacraments on a atheist in his deathbed, but centuries ago things were probably different. I add that a radical religious could think that creating an urban legend like that about famous people could be the best thing to do to save street people's souls. Maybe  Vasari was in good faith, and maybe he is right too, but I wonder which is the source about this anecdote.

What filled me with doubt about Leonardo da Vinci's possible atheism is his sentence "*As a day well spent makes sleep seem pleasant, so a life well employed makes death pleasant*". Maybe I wrong, but this looks to me the sentence of a men that  accept death like a falling asleep forever, nothing more and nothing less than that. I add that I find plausible that five centuries ago people uses keeping to himself explicit thinking about atheism, to avoid troubles; so his claim "*a small truth is better that a great lie*" could be read, maybe, as a cryptic critic to official religions.

Everyone has a sort of religiosity. But maybe Leonardo's religiosity was an "atheistic" one,  without gods or churchs. I'm very curious about this question, and probably nobody can answer to this for sure. But I wonder what data we have to get an idea about the answer and maybe someone more informed than me can be illuminating. My interpretations of the two sentences I quoted are too forced? Was Vasari source's reliable? What other sources we have about Leonardo's religious thinking?

Comment: If I remember [Isaacson](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34684622-leonardo-da-vinci?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=k2U62sWMgo&rank=1) correctly, we don't really know: there are indications for atheism and also for Catholicism, but what Leonardo himself thought is a bit uncertain and may have changed throughout his life. I didn't, admittedly, really focus on that part of the biography though so not quite prepared to answer.

Comment: [The Strait Dope](https://www.straightdope.com/21342837/was-leonardo-da-vinci-religious) has a brief but helpful take on this question.